# Bug in Lualatex: not printing characters from calculation

Tags: luatex, matrices, lua, luacode, directlua

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
local matrix = require "matrix"
local complex = require "complex"
function cmatrix(n)
return matrix(n):replace(complex)
end
function det(m)
tex.sprint(matrix.det(cmatrix(m)))
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\matrixdet}[1]{\directlua{det(#1)}}
\matrixdet{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{"7+8i",8,10}}}
\end{document}
```

Here I am using matrix.lua and complex.lua from the following links.

https://github.com/davidm/lua-matrix/blob/master/lua/matrix.lua

https://github.com/davidm/lua-matrix/blob/master/lua/complex.lua

The expected answer is -3-24i. However it gives the answer -3-24. The character i is not printed. This works well in lua itself. But it seems to be a bug in lualatex. How can it be over come? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: copy matrix.lua and complex.lua from the given links to the working folder. Then compile with lualatex.

Comment: Rather than a bug in LuaTeX, I'd suspect a bug in `complex.lua` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be an issue in how `tex.sprint` interprets complex numbers. As a solution, you can convert it to a string before printing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
local matrix = require "matrix"
local complex = require "complex"
function cmatrix(n)
return matrix(n):replace(complex)
end
function det(m)
tex.sprint(tostring(matrix.det(cmatrix(m))))
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\matrixdet}[1]{\directlua{det(#1)}}
\matrixdet{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{"7+8i",8,10}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast and correct explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike the Lua `print` function, which implicitly applies `tostring`to its argument, `tex.sprint` is defined to print each entry of a table separately if its argument is a table. The complex number is a two item table with the real and imaginary part with a custom `tostring` function that adds the `i`.

So `print(matrix.det(cmatrix(m)))` invokes `tostring` and prints `-3-24i` but `tex.sprint` applies the normal numeric `tostring` to each element of the table separately so prints `-3` then `-24`. If you explicitly apply `tostring` before calling `tex.sprint`  then the function specified for the complex number table will be used, resulting in `"-3-24i"` again.

Comment: In Lua 5.4 `print` no longer calls `tostring`, but instead uses `luaL_tolstring`.  This is functionally very similar to the old behaviour but overriding `tostring` will no longer work with `print`.  Instead the `__tostring` metafunction has to be used.